# having sqrt() problem in python, I am using Visual Studio Code software to do the python practice

Tags: python

Why does my terminal show **(8+0j)** instead of **8.0** after input **print(sqrt(64))**?
Is it my setting fault?

[image: 1]

Comment: Where did you import `sqrt` from? If you imported from `cmath` then that is why. If you import from `math` or `numpy` then you shouldn't see this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using cmath ? the sqrt function in cmath returns a complex number instead of a float
You should import sqrt from math instead of cmath it return a float

```
from math import sqrt
print(sqrt(x))
```

Comment: Fun math fact: you can use x**0.5 instead of math.sqrt(x) but it's significantly slower

Comment: The way that you teach me to add **from math import sqrt** is useful, and also thanks for tell **the Fun math fact**!

Answer (score -5):

`pip install python-math` <- install the math module if you haven't install it.

## import the math module

import math

print(math.sqrt(4)) <- out put 2.0

Comment: The math module is always built-in.  There is never a need to install it.